# How to place sum values (from MySQL using PHP) above presentation table?

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking for simple, the best practical way of placing summed value above HTML table.

Normally loops can generate sums after the loop is finished that is below the table of all results. It may be very difficult when the table is very long and we need to scroll down every time to see the sum of sales. Do I need to run two loops or is there any trick to do that? Task seems very simple. In below code I am summing Quantities from all orders and Total Sales values:

```
$lp=1; $total=0; $total_qt=0;
while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$total += $record['Total'];
$total_qt += $record['Qt'];
echo '<tr style="background-color:'. ((next($colour) == true) ? current($colour) :     reset($colour)).'">
<td> ' . $lp++ . '</td>
<td class="bolder"> ' . $record['Name'] . '</td>
<td> ' . $record['Product'] . '</td>';
if ($invoice=="on") echo '<td style="font-size:11px">' . $record['Invoice'] . '</td>';
echo '<td> ' . $record['despatched'] . '</td>
<td> ' . $record['Qt'] . '</td>
<td> ' . $record['Price'] . '</td>
<td class="align_right"> ' . $record['Total'] . '</td>';

echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table><div class="stat_total">Qt: '.$total_qt.'  Total: &pound;'.$total.'</div>    </div>';
```

Comment: You can have a JavaScript function do that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a variable to store your output while you are in the loop, rather than `echo` it, and when you finished the loop then `echo` the stored results with both totals before and after them. Like this:

```
$lp=1; $total=0; $total_qt=0;
$output = ''; //here you temporarily save your output
while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$total += $record['Total'];
$total_qt += $record['Qt'];
$output .= '<tr style="background-color:'. ((next($colour) == true) ? current($colour) :     reset($colour)).'">
<td> ' . $lp++ . '</td>
<td class="bolder"> ' . $record['Name'] . '</td>
<td> ' . $record['Product'] . '</td>';
if ($invoice=="on") $output .= '<td style="font-size:11px">' . $record['Invoice'] . '</td>';
$output .= '<td> ' . $record['despatched'] . '</td>
<td> ' . $record['Qt'] . '</td>
<td> ' . $record['Price'] . '</td>
<td class="align_right"> ' . $record['Total'] . '</td>';

$output .= '</tr>';
}
//Now you can put a div with the Total both at the start and end of the table 
echo '<div class="stat_total">Qt: '.$total_qt.'  Total: &pound;'.$total.'</div>';
echo $output . '</table>';
echo '<div class="stat_total">Qt: '.$total_qt.'  Total: &pound;'.$total.'</div>    </div>';
```

Answer (score 1):

By using the `SUM()` SQL function you'll be able to access the sums without needing to run PHP:

**SQL**

`SELECT SUM(Total) FROM Orders`